# How can I give to player points with ajax but secured?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a virtual world game that I developed with jQuery, AJAX and PHP. Virutal World like club penguin. Now, I want to add a game into the virtual world - like bubbles or whatever. The main problem its that the game in ajax, so if the player got 20 points in the game - in the ajax request I have the player points and the player can change the ajax request to any points that he want. How can I do it secured? Thanks

Comment: Why do you think, that if this was closed the first time (based on the [on hold] in the question body), that it won't get closed this time?

Comment: @Bálint His question was set on hold at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424182/how-can-i-give-to-player-points-with-ajax-but-secured) because a moderator suggested him to post here instead

Comment: Ahh, understandable

Comment: The short answer is "You can't; run your logic on the server." See also https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37392/anti-cheat-javascript-for-browser-html5-game and https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113281/prevent-cheating-in-html-javascript-game.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Hi dude, What to do In the end, I did not really understand what these articles you brought me. Is there any code that actually tells me how to hide the code from the user?

Comment: "You can't" If the player runs the game logic and the "points" on their own client, there is nothing you can do about it. The solution is to have you game run on your server, so it's only your server that has the authority to "give points" to the player. The other option is to not make the game multi-player, or have them share their score only with the people they know. Ultimately, make the score meaningless and in such a way that it does not affect the other players.